# como iterar sobre numeros y devolver true si el numero empieza con 9?

Tags: javascript, bucles, javascript-metodo

hola he estado tratando de realizar un ejercicio pero hasta aqui llegue:

//Desarrolle una función que recibe como parámetro un número entero n.
//Debe retornar true si el entero inicia con 9 y false en otro caso.

```
function empiezaConNueve(n) {
const resp = n.toString();`
const newResp = resp.filter(iterator => iterator[0] == '9');
console.log(newResp);
}
empiezaConNueve(234)
```

bueno, supuestamente el metodo toString() convierte un numero entero a un string.
ya siendo un string lo puedo iterar y validar la condicion con filter, guardando la respuesta en newResp, pero me retorna error, estoy por buen camino?? o mi logica anda mal?

gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: `function empiezaConNueve(n) { return n.toString().startsWith('9') }`

Comment: n.toString()[0] == '9'

Answer (score 5):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es verificar que el primer caracter de la string es igual a 9. Hecha un vistazo:

```js
const empiezaConNueve = (n) => n.toString()[0] === '9';

console.log(empiezaConNueve(234));
console.log(empiezaConNueve(9234));
```

Comment: muchas gracias, y en una sola linea, que grande que eres!! capo!

Answer (score 1):

No puedes hacer filter a un string. Lo correcto sería convertir el string a un array, es decir, separar los caracteres del string a elementos de un arreglo, esto lo podrías hacer con el método [**`split()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
// Desarrolle una función que recibe como parámetro un número entero n.
// Debe retornar true si el entero inicia con 9 y false en otro caso.

function empiezaConNueve(n) {
  // Convertimos en String a "n" y lo dividimos en elementos de un arreglo.
  const resp = n.toString().split('');
  // Recorremos el arreglo y filtramos si hay un "9" en la posición 0.
  const newResp = resp.filter(iterator => iterator[0] === '9');

 // Si encuentra el "9" en la posición 0, retornará "true".
  if (newResp[0] === '9') {
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false);
  }
}

empiezaConNueve(323);
empiezaConNueve(965);
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta, se nota que manipulas bien los datos, saludos

Answer (score 1):

bueno gracias por sus aportes, al final lo termine resolviendo de la siguente manera (pero sus soluciones van mejor). este es mi codigo:

```
function empiezaConNueve(n) {
const resp = n.toString(); 
for(let i = 0; i < resp.length; i++){
if(resp[i][0] === '9'){//aca verifico que solo valide el primer indice(corrijanme si estoy equivocado)
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
};
```

}
}

saludos y gracias por ser comunidad.